# ADB Backup: Will it erase root?

Tags: backup, bootloader, root-access, adb

This may sound like a stupid question, but I have a Honor 5x I'd like to root, and I want to use adb backup to backup all my phone's data so I can restore it after unlocking my bootloader (which erases the phone's data).

My question is:  If I backup with `adb backup -all`, when I'll restore my phone's data, will it erase root? Probably not, but I just don't want to risk it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Backing up and restoring won't affect root.

Basically, `adb backup` backups a portion of `/data` partition, while rooting mostly affects `/system` partition and soemtimes `/` (boot ramdisk, for system-less root). You can safely back it up and proceed on rooting it before restoring the backup.

Comment: What happens when I choose both System Apps and User Apps in backup settings, does it work as you mentioned?